# Why is a .class file not being created?

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

I am promgramming for the first time for with a mac running OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite and I'm using Smultron7 as a text editor. Whenever I try to compile and run code within the text editor or terminal an error appears on the console. For example:

```
input:

    public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }
}
    Output: 

    Documents/:Users:KH:HelloWorld.java:1: error: class HelloWorld is public, should be declared in a file named HelloWorld.java
    public class HelloWorld{
           ^
    1 error
```

It seems like a .class file is not being created and I'm not sure why. I've also downloaded Java Development Kit 8 from the oracle website.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Did you put the input in a file named HelloWorld.java, as the message indicates? Do you run the compiler to get the message? I'm not familiar with Smultron7, and not that familiar with Yosemite - are you entering a command on a command line, or is the editor part of a system that edits and compiles java code? The error message says clearly what the problem is, to fix it we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it is written: 'should be declared in a file named HelloWorld.java'.

Java has a rule that you can only have one and only one public class in a source code file. Furthermore, the source code file must be named after this only public class.

So, I guess that you need to save your code into a file called 'HelloWorld.java' and then try to compile it again.